# How to animate FillColor of MapPolygon (BingMap MapControl) UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

**I want to use a ColorAnimation on the FillColor Property of a MapPolygon.**

I created a HeatMap with the `BingMap` Control for UWP
[Heatmap Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i4X6.jpg)

I got a function, where i calculate a new `FillColor` for each `MapPolygon`. I want now to use a `ColorAnimation` instead of just changing the `FillColor` from the old value to the new value.

```
//Instead of 
statePolygon.FillColor = backGroundColor;

//I want to use something like the following
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
animation.From = statePolygon.FillColor;
animation.To = newBackGroundColor;
animation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5));
storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(MapPolygon.FillColor)");
Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard, statePolygon);
storyboard.Begin();
```

But with the storyboard code i always get an `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` which tells me the Animation target not specified.

I tried a lot of values for the second parameter of the `Storyboard.SetTargetproperty`... nothing worked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues.

In the code snippet you posted you are using `myStoryboard` in `SetTarget` instead of the `storyboard` variable. Fixing that seems to resolve the `COMException`. But the polygon color still will not animate.

The reason is that the `FillColor` property is not a `DependencyProperty`. To enable animation of this property, you will have to enable dependent animation on your animation before starting the `Storyboard`:

```
animation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
```

The difference between dependent and independent animations is [described in MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx#dependent). Note that the performance of this animation may be a bit worse than for independent animations.

Comment: thx alot :) it worked now. The myStoryboard in SetTarget was a Storyboard i created in the xaml, and forgot to change it.